# Can Adobe's filevault tool (VLT) be configured to ignore files?

Tags: adobe, aem

If it can, where would this be configured?

From the documentation, all mention of ignoring files is about excluding `.vlt` from **SVN commits**, but we're facing the opposite issue — we'd like to exclude files that are on the file system from **VLT commits** — e.g. `.DS_Store`, `*.iml`, etc.

VLT creates a `.vault` folder in the user's home directory, similar to `.subversion`, but this just seems to hold authentication details.

The programme also doesn't seem to allow an ignore property to be set via propset — I tried this with a similar syntax to SVN (`vlt propset -R vlt:ignore .DS_Store *`) and received a fairly useless, (& overly optimistic for future improvement) error message:

> Generic properies not supported, yet

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the ignores to your META-INF/vault/settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vault version="1.0">
  <ignore name=".svn"/>
</vault>
```

Comment: Cheers. Checked my own machine just now & have it already! Was helping a colleague get set-up though & couldn't think of where to put it. One of those start of project configurations that you only make once every few months :)

Answer (score 1):

sure.

In the vault config directory, where the filter.xml is, create a file settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vault version="1.0">
   <ignore name=".svn"/>
  <ignore name=".DS_Store"/>
</vault>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna solve it in a more general matter you can use a user-config similar to SVN in your home directory.

```
$ cat ~/.vault/settings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vault version="1.0">
  <ignore name=".svn"/>
  <ignore name="._*"/>
  <ignore name="release.txt"/>
  <ignore name=".git"/>
  <ignore name=".gitignore"/>
  <ignore name="*/generated(/?)*"/>
</vault>
```

Where .svn, .git and so on is ignored as well as generated AEM files (s.a. less to css).

Answer (score 0):

just go to the **src/main/content** folder where **jcr_root** folder lie.

You will see the folder "**META-INF**" and go in to **META-INF/vault** folder.

open the setting.xml file. You will see the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <vault version="1.0">
     <ignore name=".svn"/>
     <ignore name="._*"/>
     <ignore name="release.txt"/>
     <ignore name=".git"/>
     <ignore name=".DS_Store"/>
     <ignore name=".gitignore"/>
     <ignore name="*/generated(/?)*"/>
  </vault>
```

You can add the ignoring files/folder here. I have added the Eclipes project folder .DS_Store.